# Packaging executable Jar - including dependent Jars

Tags: executable-jar

I need to come up with single executable Jar which has dependent jars and source class bundled togather. Is there any way we could achieve this using ANT build ? Please help me. I tried many options and nothing seems to work out.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse makes this easy. Just export your working project as a Runnable Jar File. It will even create an ANT script for you to automate the process.